# How to decrypt Emotet's TLS traffic by MITMProxy

Tags: tls, malware, man-in-the-middle, proxy, emotet

I have a question about Emotet's TLS traffic:

[image]
[image]

Using MITMProxy, I have successfully decrypted TLS traffic with Emotet's C2 server and can read the contents of the traffic.
https://mitmproxy.org

However, although we were able to see the contents of the TLS traffic, the TLS traffic did not terminate successfully.

After a little research, I found that self-certification has a feature called pinning.

Is the inability to compound the contents of Emotet's traffic with the C2 server because the pinning feature is getting in the way?

My objective is to extract the cookie values contained in the TLS communications of the infected PC and swap them with cookies in the TLS communications of the virtual machine in preparation to infect the virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

If it's doing certificate pinning, it has to know what fingerprint (or some other property) of the certificate or public key it should expect. This value has to be stored somewhere on the system executing the function.

You can either disassemble the binary and attempt to dig down how it verifies that the cert matches the pinned entry, and replace either the function or the pinned value with one matching your own - or you can fire it up in a debugger and attempt to find it there.

Comment: I have to ask, is that eck1 and ecs1 in this URL?
https://tria.ge/230103-ge2cwsad22

Comment: I don't know. Possibly.